# Calculate median across multiple lists vertically

Tags: r, list, median

Say I have three lists, each one containing the result of a test:

```
listA <- list(10, 5, 4)
listB <- list(2, 8, 3)
listC <- list(1, 5, 3)
```

I want to find the median of those lists by position *vertically*. So the results for each position would be:

- First position: 2
- Second position: 5
- Third position: 3

How can I achieve this in R? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map()` to combine the three lists vertically, and then compute each median by `lapply()`.

```
sapply(Map(c, listA, listB, listC), median)

# [1] 2 5 3
```

---

You can also use `transpose()` from `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

map_dbl(transpose(mget(ls(pattern = 'list'))), ~ median(flatten_dbl(.x)))

# [1] 2 5 3
```

Or using `pmap()`:

```
pmap_dbl(mget(ls(pattern = 'list')), ~ median(c(...)))

# [1] 2 5 3
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for providing both a tidyverse example and the lapply example. One more question: Say my three lists are stored as a column in a dataframe with each list forming a row. How would the code change to accommodate that?

Comment: @R.Baratheon Try `purrr::pmap(df$var, ~ median(c(...)))`, where `var` is the column you store three lists.

Comment: One more question... Say I want to determine how often a given list contains the median result. How would I do that? I'm essentially trying to calculate the probability that a list will contain the median result.

Comment: @R.Baratheon I'm not sure about your question. Do you mean `2` in `listA`, `5` in `listB`, and `3` in `listC`? If not, please give an example.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. We know that `listA` held the median once (5), `listB` held the median once (3), and `listC` held the median twice (5 and 3). Therefore, out of the three lists, `listC` held the median two out of three times. We would say `listC` has a 67% of chance of holding the median.

My original question should have had two pieces now that I write this out: How to compute the median (completed thanks to your help), and then how to calculate the probability of the median (outlined above). Let me know if you think this is better as a separate question. Thanks again.

Comment: @R.Baratheon `listB` should hold the median twice (2, 3), right? If I got the rule correctly, then try this `sapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'list')), function(x) sum(unlist(x) %in% med)/length(x))`, where `"med"` is the output of the first question. Remember to store it as a vector, i.e. `c(2, 5, 3)`, not `list(2, 5, 3)`. If it still doesn't help, please post a new question on SO because it should be an extended question.

Comment: I will go ahead and post a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, the new post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864013/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-being-a-median-across-a-list-using-r

Answer (score 2):

Get all the individual lists together in one list using `mget`, combine them in a matrix and take row-wise median.

```
matrixStats::rowMedians(sapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'list')), unlist))
#[1] 2 5 3
```

Or keeping it in base R :

```
mat <- sapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'list')), unlist)
apply(mat, 1, median)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the data types a little bit to get it to work, might look at the other answers first, but this is what I did to get what you asked for. I put the values in vectors, and then in a data frame instead of a list, and then called the `median()` function on the respectable columns you wanted.

```
listA <- c(10, 5, 4)
listB <- c(2, 8, 3)
listC <- c(1, 5, 3)

test <- as.data.frame(rbind(listA, listB, listC))

median(test[,1])
[1] 2
median(test[,2])
[1] 5
median(test[,3])
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `map` and `transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = ('^list[A-C]'))) %>% 
   transpose %>%
   map_dbl(~ flatten_dbl(.x) %>% median)
#[1] 2 5 3
```